# Python-emacs communication broken

Tags: python, comint

When I call run-python, I get the buffer with python REPL and the prompt.

- I can type stuff, but when I press enter there is no reaction (except the cursor moves in new line).
- If I press C-c C-c (comint-interrupt-subjob), I get a new prompt, but I don't see any output of the previous commands.
- If I use python-shell-send-region or if I evaluate (comint-send-string "*Python*" "print 5\n"), I don't see any output in Python buffer, but the elisp function returns without error.
- I can end the python process by pressing C-d (comint-delchar-or-maybe-eof).

The same problem occurs both with python and ipython (I tried python-shell-switch-to-shell with both). The Emacs communication also doesn't work when trying to use Mozart programming system, which also uses comint. Some other comint based modes on the other hand (scheme, shell) work without problems.

If I run python inside emacs shell I get the same behavior as above. After C-d, the python ends and the shell works normally again.

I've also tried starting emacs without init files.

Versions:

- Python 2.7.8
- Emacs 24.3.1 (also saw the problem with 24.4.1)
- built-in python.el
- Debian Jessie

Comment: Have you looked into `elpy`. I use that for python development in emacs and everything works quite well. I don't have any experience w/ pure `python-mode`.

Comment: No, so far it seems that python.el has more or less what I need. Has elpy any fundamental advantages?

Comment: @MatejFröbe elpy primarily does a bunch of helpful configuration for you to get common python issues smoothed out. Things like autocomplete, pep8 / flakes, testing, etc. all work reasonably well out of the box. It also has integration with pyvenv that might help with your python repl issue.

Comment: @elarson I mostly need good integration with IPyhon, a debugger which shows me the current location in file and the ability to jump to the file and line of failed unit test. All of these normally work reasonably well out of the box with python.el. It works for me on Windows and in virtual machine with fresh install of Debian Jessie, but it is broken on one particualar machine and I'm running out of ideas how to debug it with reasonable amount of effort.

But thanks for the suggestion anyway, I might look at elpy if I have bigger needs in the future.

Comment: @MatejFröbe I gave ipython a try and I didn't see it provide links to files in tracebacks. That said, [pytest.el](http://github.com/ionrock/pytest-el) (which I wrote) as well as elpy's test running functionality can run a test in a compilation buffer where you can easily hop between files in a traceback.

Comment: @elarson M-x compile works fine for running tests, but I use a simple wrapper function for it. For tracebacks in python shell I use [this function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12101330/4039101) ,modified for Python formatting.

Comment: This seems to be a system or Emacs configuration problem; there's not enough information to debug it (and I don't think it's a good fit for the site). Try debugging using `emacs -Q`, and if the problem persists you can report it to the Emacs maintainers using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.